# Deleting items from list view bug

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

So i have a problem with my listview when i delete data from my database.
The problem is that some other items in my list view get mest up
i have noted that when i delete the second from the bottom the problem occurs

Database

```
//getRowRevers
public Cursor getAllRowre(){
    String where=null;
    String orderBy =  ID_KEY + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEY, where, null, null, null,ID_KEY + " DESC", null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}    

//delete 
    public boolean deleatRow(String idRow){
        String where=ID_KEY+"="+idRow;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }
    public void deleatAll(){
        Cursor cursor=getAllRowre();
        long idRow=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID_KEY);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                deleatRow(cursor.getString((int) idRow));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }   
    }
```

So here is how i managed to get the list view working i think this method is not the best and maybe this is the reason and i don't know how to do it in a different way

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            int mySuperInt=dbJ.countCases()+ 1 -position-2;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), JornalListViewClick.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName",mySuperInt);

            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    });
```

PS the list view is always changing when the user pass data

Comment: the bug is the when a item is removed from the database the some other data is messed up

Comment: Messed up how, though?

Comment: the data is not displaying like it is empty

Comment: Have you thought of using a CursorLoader?

Comment: but just the lest one

Comment: i think it is not a problem in the adapter but in the on clickListener for the listView because on the list view there is everything ok but when i open up the item the data is missing